# Rebus this, Rebus that

Tags: knowledge, rebus

> **Here are three medium difficulty, rebus puzzles,**

[image]

Comment: I can't make out the critter in the first one well enough to ID it.

Comment: Used image search and found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara_(mammal)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A work in progress:

1.

> (With help from ffao!) Python = (pai + marathon - mara)

2.

> (Per Aiden F. Pierce, who beat me to it!) Rattlesnake = (rat + less + N + ache).

3.

> Hypertext mark-up language = (Hyperbeam - beam + text) + (mark + up) + language

Answer (score 15):

For 1:

> Python? (pai + marathon - mara)

Comment: That is correct :D

Answer (score 15):

2.

> Rattlesnake (rat + less + N + ache).

Others have already covered the other two.

Comment: Yep that is correct :D